# Post__not_in only removing first 2 pages

Tags: wp-query

I am using post__not_in to remove pages from a query but it's ignoring anything more than 2 items

My code:

```
$selected_check = array();
  $checks = new WP_Query( 'post_type=page&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC&posts_per_page=-1');
  while($checks->have_posts()){
   $checks->the_post();
   global $post;
   $this_check = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_hide_home', true);
   if($this_check == 'on'){
    $selected_check[] = $post->ID;
   }
  } 
  wp_reset_postdata();

  $new_check = implode(", ", $selected_check);

  $query1 = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'orderby' => 'menu_order',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'posts_per_page' => '-1',
  'post__not_in' => array($new_check)
 ));
```

My $new_checks array is currently 51, 76, 10, 21 but it's only working on the first 2 items

Is there something I am missing in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`post__not_in` should be an array of post IDs - remove the `implode` line and just pass `$selected_check` as the argument value instead of `array( $new_check )`.

Comment: Cheers, I was trying to be too clever for my own good, I am not sure why but I thought I had to use the implode to add the commas to make the array work :)